# allow textbox input from barcode scanner only and restrict any input from keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is functionality like, the textbox accepts input from only barcode scanner and restricts any other input from keyboard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bar Code Scanner and Keyboard Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606005/bar-code-scanner-and-keyboard-issue)

Comment: try to prevent the default action of keypress event

Comment: @Harsha, sorry for misguide. This is my question. How will i achieve tis functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is for restricting input from keyboard .. Just try connecting your barcode scanner and check if it works..

```
 textBox.onkeypress = function(e) {
       e = e || window.event;
       var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
       if (/\D/.test(String.fromCharCode(charCode))) {
           return false;
       }
    };
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/JCUT2/5/)

For Alphanumeric

Chk this

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/JCUT2/83/)

Comment: I want this to accept alphanumeric? should I say : e.which == "alphanumeric" ??

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this later .. our barcode scanner is now not available :)

Comment: I could still use keyboard. why is this?

Comment: Still able to type from keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out at http://www.deadosaurus.com/detect-a-usb-barcode-scanner-with-javascript

From the link, I have modified to auto clear the text when it is not meeting 10 character length criteria, which can assume as not meeting 10 character length  criteria = not input from barcode scanner.

I am using ASP.NET, below is my sample:

For ASP code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxComponentPartNumber" runat="server" onkeypress="AutoClearOrSetInputText(event,this.id);" ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxAssemblyPartNumber" runat="server" onkeypress="AutoClearOrSetInputText(event,this.id);" ></asp:TextBox>
```

For JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//This variables is for AutoClearOrSetInputText function
var pressed = false;
var chars = [];

//This function will auto clear or set input text box’s text value
function AutoClearOrSetInputText(eventForTextBox,idForTextBox) {

// add each entered char to the chars array
chars.push(String.fromCharCode(eventForTextBox.which));

// variable to ensure we wait to check the input we are receiving
if (pressed == false) {
// we set a timeout function that expires after 0.5 sec, once it does it clears out a list
// of characters
setTimeout(function() {
// check we have a long length e.g. it is a barcode
if (chars.length >= 10) {
// join the chars array to make a string of the barcode scanned
var barcode = chars.join(“”);
// assign value to input for barcode scanner scanned value
document.getElementById(idForTextBox).value = barcode;
}
else {
// clear value from input for non-barcode scanner scanned value
document.getElementById(idForTextBox).value = ”;
}
chars = [];
pressed = false;
}, 500);
}
// set press to true so we do not reenter the timeout function above
pressed = true;
}
</script>
```